# Prevent overflow:hidden from cutting text in the middle when using flexbox column

Tags: css, flexbox

I want to create a fixed height card with a title, body, and footer.  The title and footer can be one or more lines, and the body text should expand to fill the remaining space.

```css
.card {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  height: 192px;
  width: 300px;
  border: 1px solid;
  padding: 12px;
}

.title {
  font-size: 18px;
  font-weight: bold;
  margin-bottom: 8px;
}

.body {
  flex: 1 1 auto;
  overflow: hidden;
  overflow-wrap: break-word;
  word-wrap: break-word;
  margin-bottom: 8px;
}
```

```html
<div class="card">
  <div class="title">
    This is a title
  </div>
  <div class="body">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
  </div>
  <div>
    footer text
  </div>
</div>
```

How can I prevent the body text from being cut off?  `overflow-wrap`/`word-wrap` seem to have no effect.

Comment: In your example you're setting both a with and a height. Do you want the container to grow horizontally if the text doesn't fit?

Comment: Nope, just want fixed width.

Comment: Try the css property `overflow-y: scroll;`

Comment: so in other words, you want the last line to be either fully visible or not visible at all?

Comment: @TemaniAfif

Yes, exactly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to make the height a mutliple of the height of one line. Here is an example using CSS grid.

Resize the main container to see the magic:

```css
.card {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  height: 192px;
  width: 300px;
  border: 1px solid;
  padding: 12px;
  overflow: hidden;
  resize: both;
}

.title {
  font-size: 18px;
  font-weight: bold;
  margin-bottom: 8px;
}

.body {
  flex: 1 1 auto;
  margin-bottom: 8px;
  line-height: 1.2em; /* height of one line */
  display: grid;
  grid-template-rows: repeat(auto-fit, 1.2em); /* same as line-height here */
  grid-auto-rows: 0;
}

.body>div {
  grid-row: 1/-1;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<div class="card">
  <div class="title">
    This is a title
  </div>
  <div class="body">
    <div>
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor
      in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
    </div>
  </div>
  <div>
    footer text
  </div>
</div>
```